# Как узнать на каком input (его id) находится курсор?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня есть 4 `<input>`-а. Я набираю числа, и курсор автоматически переходит на следующий `<input>`. Как узнать id текущего (в котором находится курсор) `<input>`-а?

Comment: В какой момент времени вам нужно узнавать ID текущего `<input>`-a?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').on('focus',function(){
      var $self = $(this);
      $('#result').text($self.attr('id'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="1">
<input id="2">
<input id="3">
<input id="4">

<div id="result"></div>
```